# SolrInputDocument/tika Extraction is slow for indexing many documents

Tags: solr, apache-tika

I'm using Solr 4.5. I'm trying to loop through multiple html files to extract the data from the file, using Apache Tika 1.4. Then adding those metadata fields to the SolrInputDocument . Every time I have to loop the file and create the instance of SolrInputDocument. Indexing seems to be very slow and we have huge number of files to index. I need advice from experts here.This is the sample code which I'm using.

```
    String urlString = "http://server/solr/";
    SolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer(urlString);
    UpdateRequest updrequest = new UpdateRequest("/update");

     //For tika extraction initialisation
    BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(10 * 1024 * 1024);
    AutoDetectParser autoparser = new AutoDetectParser();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();
```

Then for every html file I call the Tika extraction method ExtractData which I have written and I pass each objects which I initialized here along with my file:

```
ExtractData(file,solr,updrequest,handler,autoparser,metadata,parseContext);
```

The code for **ExtractData** is shown below

```
public void ExtractData(String file,SolrServer solr,UpdateRequest updrequest,BodyContentHandler handler,AutoDetectParser autoparser,Metadata metadata,ParseContext parseContext) throws IOException,
        SAXException, TikaException, SolrServerException {

    SolrInputDocument solrinputdocument = new SolrInputDocument();
    metadata.set(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/html");
    autoparser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseContext);

    //loop all metadata from the extraction and add the fields to the solr
    String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();
    for (String name : metadataNames) {
        solrinputdocument.addField(name, metadata.get(name));
        }
    }
    updrequest.add(solrinputdocument);
    solr.request(updrequest);
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried to multi-thread the extraction process? So instead of extracting the docs one by one after each other extracting them in parallel.

Comment: Again, as cheffe says, extract content concurrently in different threads. Also you can use ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer that will buffer the SolrInputDocuments

Comment: Can someone give me steps on how we can create a multithreading way for this extraction . I have never worked in multithreading . Please help.

Answer (score 1):

As cheffe says, you can't use multiple threads with DIH nowadays (there was a possibility to do so in the past but was buggy and was removed). So your best bet is:

1. do the extraction with tika in its own client side program
2. use SolrJ api to send to solr
3. you do that in multiple threads, tweak the number till you see the best scenario. Also tweak the usual lucene/solr config for indexing throuput (remBufferSizeMB etc)

Comment: i removed the line 
 UpdateRequest updrequest = new UpdateRequest("/update");

and i passed the solrinputdocument directly to solr like:    solr.add(solrinputdocument);

This started running very fast. Can we do this way also by removing the Update Request. Does solr.add(solrinputdocument) will index the complete document to solr?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the AutoDetectParser with an explicit HtmlParser. I recently found that the autodetect process can be very slow, seemingly loading files multiple times.

Comment: Could it be [this Tika bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1568)? Or are you having a different problem?